# Schedule a task to update record in database in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I use Spring Webflux and my problem is that I need to write a record in database and run a task, which will update this record in DB in 30 seconds.

For example, assume that I write to DB an object with status 'RAW'. After the record was written, the timer should start and after 30 seconds status of this record should be changed to 'DONE'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Scheduler.schedule(Runnable task, long delay, TimeUnit unit)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Scheduler.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)
to schedule a task right after the record is written:

```
.flatMap(message -> writeRecord(record)
.doFinally(e -> Schedulers.single().schedule(() -> updateRecordStatus(), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```